# MySql : Outer Join Query : Some alternate better approach (overriding field value by other table's field value only if available)

Tags: mysql, performance, outer-join

I am asking this question to seek some alternate approach to get the same results which I managed to obtain as described below:

I have three tables: Account(a user), profile_parameters, Account_profile. By default, the account profile will get the parameter values defined in the base system config(profile_parameters) however, user can override those values by defining its own preference (which gets stored Account_profile), then those parameters take precedence over base system config. Following are the table structures:

**Account:**
`Account_id` (PK)
some more columns....

**Profile_parameters:**
`prfl_param_id` (PK),
`param_desc`, `param_default_value` (This is system base config value)

**Account_profile:**
`account_id`(FK to Account), `prfl_param_id`(FK to profile_parameter. param_value(Overridden value defined by user)

I managed to get the desired result from following query but I believe there must be an alternate elegant way because I am firing one sub-query to check and the other sub-query to get the overridden value, about which  I do not feel much comfortable.

```
SELECT a.account_id,pp.prfl_param_id, 
(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM account_profile ap WHERE ap.account_id=a.account_id AND ap.prfl_param_id=pp.prfl_param_id ) 
      THEN (SELECT param_value FROM account_profile ap WHERE ap.account_id=a.account_id AND ap.prfl_param_id=pp.prfl_param_id ) 
ELSE  pp.default_value END) dfd 
FROM  account a, profile_parameters pp
```

[image]

Any suggestions ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use left-join as follows:

```
select temp.account_id, temp.prfl_param_id,if(param_value is null,temp.param_default_value,param_value) dfd
from (
  select a.account_id, pp.prfl_param_id, param_default_value
  from account a, profile_parameters pp 
) temp left join account_profile ap on temp.account_id=ap.account_id and temp.prfl_param_id=ap.prfl_param_id
```

here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d455/1),

Comment: this will return only the parameters which account(user) has defined. If the user has not defined any value, the base system config value will not be returned. Moreover, it will not provide the base system value for all other accounts(users) who have not even defined any value at all.

Comment: Well, it would be more clear if you provide sample data and expected output in question.

Comment: most definitely, I was about to Up-vote it and then saw your message. Nice and pretty quick response!!

Comment: No problem. Anytime... available for help :D (except rest time.. hahaha)